# What route did you use to earn the Stunt Superstar award in Burnout Paradise?

Tags: achievements, burnout-paradise

The Stunt Superstar Paradise Award in Burnout Paradise requires you to get a x40 multiplier in a stunt run. I'm looking for suggestions from those who've gotten it. Which stunt run did you use and what was your route?

Comment: is the name of the award stunt superstar?

Comment: Yes. I believe it is #41 on the PS3 version.

Answer (score 5):

Choose a stunt run in the Downtown area of the map. The key is you don't have to worry about the time limit on a stunt run as the stunt run will continue even after the time runs out **as long as** you keep the little countdown circle going and don't crash! The countdown circle is kept going by performing stunts or more importantly a quick boost. So all you have to do when the countdown circle is about to run out is briefly boost and establish a route through Paradise City that allows you to perform a decent number of jumps and billboard smashes. There is a good amount around the Wildcats stadium area. If you need some more, head west down the Southbay Expressway and then up and into the quarry. Good luck!

Comment: Another easy way to keep the countdown circle going is to drive in reverse.

Answer (score 1):

I like to start just north of the Wildcats stadium, an dhead up the scaffolding on the left heading south, then round the back of the stadium and up the ramps here. When you come to the end and pop out onto the dual carriageway quickly go up the steps of the building on the north side and a hairpin to drop out through a billboard.

Then take the ramp over the water to get onto the South Bay Expressway. Just before the bridge turn around and use all the jumps in the dockyard. Back around onto the expressway and over the bridge this time, using the jumps.

Head off to the right and drift all the way to the top of the dam and get to the main entrance to the quarry and use the half ramp down into the quarry. Use a couple of jumps in there and come back out the main entrance.

Use the ramp to the west of the dam to head back down and head off past the dirt track onto south mountain drive. Loads of stunts all the way round until the end of north mountain drive and you should have your x40 multiplier by then.

The key is little dabs of boost when your circle is almost gone.

Comment: I started out exactly as you did, except I continued over the bridge, using the jumps and the billboards in the middle. My multiplier determined how many big air jumps I took in the quarry...one, two or all three. Two key things, though: To keep your boost up on the way there, you need to drive into opposing traffic. Also, don't forget the flatspins and barrel roll opportunities.

Answer (score 1):

Mine took less than 10 minutes! Ok start a stunt run somewhere next to the airfield and then go to the airfield and score at least 13x barrel rolling, then if you drive outside and around the airfield you should find at least 7x more (there's gotta be like 4 billboards and 3 airtime places). By then you should be at least on a 20x multiplier, if you got that, take a 1 minute drive to and thru the dam and to the quarry, now try to make sure you barrel roll off the halfpipe which will give you a + 4x, go around the building and head back up the the big ledge, keep going Untill you reach a jump and flat spin off it, (2x) go back up to the ledge and jump thru the billboard flat spinning (4x) 
Go around and do the remaining 2 or so jumps off the ledge, then head up to the ledge, turn around and speed your way thru the billboard overlooking the broken bridge/train tracks. By then you should at least have around 36-39x multiplier going. After you get that,get back on s.mountain drive and barrel roll of the superjump right across the quarry entrance! You will define tely reach 40x, if not more by then. You can go ahead and keep building up the multiplier if you're trying to set a score or something but there you go! P.s  set time to midnight for less traffic ;)

Answer (score 1):

Avoid barrel rolls. Try simple jumps. Trick - when you are about to jump from somewhere, remember to press left or right button along with handbrake. By that, the car will not only jump, but also spin in the air giving you extra multiples. Don't forget to press nitro button before red clock cycle completes. And always use light stunt cars. My favourites are P12 and Hyperion. My record in stunt run is 21,923,460. I could not remember what exactly was my multiple, but I could safely say it was between x85 and x90.